# Display an animated gif in parallel to a Tkinter process, how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, graphics

I searched all around the web and the StackOverflow website, but didn't find any suitable answer to my problem.

I have a Python class used to create gifs objects:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from itertools import count

class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    
    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        self.loc = 0
        self.frames = []

        try:
            for i in count(1):
                self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(self.frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=self.frames[0])
        else:
            self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        self.config(image="")
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.loc += 1
            self.loc %= len(self.frames)
            self.config(image=self.frames[self.loc])
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
```

Which can be used as follows (supposing we defined a frame before):

```
gif = ImageLabel( frame )
gif.load( "path/to/spinner.gif" )
gif.place( anchor="center", relx= 0.7, rely=0.5 )
```

I would like to be able to run this created gif in parallel with another command, in the same frame. For example: let's say I am clicking a button which performs a long operation, in this case I would like to have a gif displayed among it, which runs parallely and be destroyed after the process finishes.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Run the long operation in a thread.

Comment: @acw1668 can you provide me an example? thanks.

Comment: Study the official document on [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module.

Comment: @acw1668 I know how to use threads. The fact is that the long operation is inside a button command. How Could I solve it?

Comment: Simply create another function to start the original function in a thread and then set the `command` option to the new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by simply placing a gif and sending in parallel a function to execute the job:

```
self.spinner_gif.place( anchor = "center", relx = 0.7, rely = 0.55 )
threading.Thread( target = self.Function ).start()
```

and then at the end of the `Function` function:

```
self.spinner_gif.place_forget()
```